# Is there a IFrame element available for Kotlin Multiplatform?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm looking for an Iframe-type element to only show a simple YouTube video using the URL that supports both Android and iOS using Jetpack Compose.

Comment: Define more what you want with an "iframe type element".  Iframe isn't generally a concept in other platforms, because it isn't needed-  it only exists as a concept because of weaknesses in html security.

Comment: Just need to show a YouTube video in a part of the view.

Comment: Just use a VideoPlayer